# How do I sum values if both column, row and cell value match conditions?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have two sheets: flight control and total hours control. [Link to sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jxm8Moc8sKm7UYgI75ThiqzlecTykwgafPmQDIyyouY/edit#gid=0).

Flight Control:

[image: Flight Control]

Total Hours:

[image: Total Hours]

**What I want**: On **Total Hours**, Sum the **Flight Time** if:

**Column Name**(L.D.1) matches row on **Line**; row **Pilot** matches row **Pilot**; **cell** has a value of 1.

I'm using this for cell C2, and it works:

```
=SUMIFS('Flight Time'!B:B;'Flight Time'!A:A;B2;'Flight Time'!C:C;"1")
```

And it works, giving me this:

[image]

However, this isn't very practical. I have to redo the formula every time a new pilot is introduced. And if I move columns around, it stops working.

**What I need**: To base my conditions on a text search. Something like:

```
If column name in  {Flight Time!C:F} matches string on {row in col Line}, and Pilot = Pilot, and cell value = 1, SUM
```

In other words, I need to scale this. The final product will have dozens of pilots and L.D.s, so I need to be able to move things around.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: [Here it is](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jxm8Moc8sKm7UYgI75ThiqzlecTykwgafPmQDIyyouY/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Have you considered using apps script to do it? See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet

Comment: I have considered, but I since my JS skills are quite basic I thought I'd give this question a try. I was doing it in Python+Pandas iterating throught column + row names, but this seems to go in a different logic (also It has to work on gsheets alone, so I put python aside. User @player0 awnsered it already and I'm working on trying to make his code work, do you think it's the right path, before heading to Google Scripts? I'm honestly still trying to figure out the ins and outs of his code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is similar to player0's but it anticipates a Flight Time tab that expands infinitely sideways as well as down.

You would start a new tab and place this formula in cell A1.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY('Flight Time'!C1:1&"|"&'Flight Time'!A2:A&"|"&OFFSET('Flight Time'!C2;;;ROWS('Flight Time'!C2:C);COLUMNS('Flight Time'!C2:2))*'Flight Time'!B2:B&CHAR(10);;9^99));;9^99);CHAR(10);0;0)));"|";0;0);"select Col1,Col2, SUM(Col3) where Col3>0 group by Col1,Col2 label Col1'Line',Col2'Pilot',SUM(Col3)'Total Hours'"))
```

Sometimes in complicated formulas like this, it can be difficult to translate to your real sheet if you haven't placed the sample data in exactly the same layout on the sample as it is on your real sheet.  If that is the case here, change the layout of the sample so that it better matches your real data, and I can try to update the formula.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(C2:F="",,"♠"&C1:F1&"♦"&A2:A&"♣♥"&B2:B),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♥"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")),,999^99)), "♦♣"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for the awnser. Honestly I'm still trying to figure out this code, I'm guessing I'm supposed to fill the playing card icons with my column names and pilots? Haven't quite got it to work yet.

Comment: if C2:F range is not empty then it concentrates row 1 headers with column A and column B. then it collapses all results into one single cell and the combo of Split will cut it down into two columns. then query performs sum of durations and results are again collapsed into one single column from where Split formula cuts it into 3 final columns